# Extra padding when using Optical Bounds in background image

Tags: android, android-layout

The optical bounds feature introduced in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#UI seems to add an additional padding setting to the parent layout.
In the screenshot below, 3 example fragments can be seen:

1. A fragment with the default setting layoutMode="clipBounds"
2. A fragment with layoutMode="opticalBounds"
3. A fragment with layoutMode="opticalBounds", but the background image is a simple color.

Fragment #2 has a additional padding in the root layout. My goal is to remove that padding, so that I can place & layout the TextView entirely based on it's inner optical bounds.

How can I remove the inner padding created by the 2nd fragment? I have already tried setting the padding to 0dp or "-11dp" but this is not what I hope on doing.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Code:

#### Fragment 1:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_with_stroke_gray"
        android:text="lorem ipsum etc"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

#### Fragment 2:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_with_stroke_gray"
        android:text="lorem ipsum etc"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

#### Fragment 3

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ffffcc"
        android:text="lorem ipsum etc"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

#### Activity Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="40dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="opticalboundstest.WithoutOpticalBoundsFragment"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="opticalboundstest.WithOpticalBoundsFragment"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="opticalboundstest.WithWorkingOpticalBoundsFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Simulator screenshot]

The shadow image being used:

[image: Shadow 9-Patch image]

Answer (score 0):

> Fragment #2 has a additional padding in the root layout

Actually, it is not padding. Gap between blue and red line is called optical bounds (or optical insets).
[Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#UI) you can see:

> All layout elements also honor the optical bounds of their child views, adapting their own bounds based on the optical bounds of the views within them.

And look at computeOpticalInsets() in ViewGroup

```
Insets computeOpticalInsets() {
    if (isLayoutModeOptical()) {
        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int bottom = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mChildrenCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
                Insets insets = child.getOpticalInsets();
                left =   Math.max(left,   insets.left);
                top =    Math.max(top,    insets.top);
                right =  Math.max(right,  insets.right);
                bottom = Math.max(bottom, insets.bottom);
            }
        }
        return Insets.of(left, top, right, bottom);
    } else {
        return Insets.NONE;
    }
}
```

So, optical bounds of parent are maximum of optical bounds of his children.

> My goal is to remove that padding, so that I can place & layout the TextView entirely based on it's inner optical bounds.

You can not place TextView entirely based on it's inner optical bounds, because its parent can has other children with optical bounds.
Why do you want to remove this gap? It is not visible to user

Comment: I want to remove the gaps because I need translate a PS design (following a grid structure) into a 100% correct layout. The logic (Math.max for child insets) is exactly what makes this a bit difficult as various assets (9-Patch) have different optical bounds and I can never be sure which inset is currently being used. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to disable the Insets completely using Java reflection.

```
/**
 * Helper class for the optical bounds layout mode.
 */
public class Bounds {
    private static final String TAG = Bounds.class.getName();

    /**
     * Disables insets for a given {@link android.view.View} or {@link android.view.ViewGroup}.
     * This method should be called during the construction phase of the <code>target</code> object.
     *
     * @param target Target object to disable the layout insets.
     * @return Whether the operation succeeded.
     */
    public static boolean disableLayoutInsets(final View target) {
        try {
            final Field mLayoutInsets = View.class.getDeclaredField("mLayoutInsets");
            mLayoutInsets.setAccessible(true);

            final Class c = Class.forName("android.graphics.Insets");
            final Field f = c.getDeclaredField("NONE");

            mLayoutInsets.set(target, f.get(target));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```